# Javascript: How to use setAttribute "href" for a URL refering to another domain

Tags: javascript, href, absolute-path, setattribute

In my html code I am using an `<a>` tag with empty `<href>` as the url is not known at the beginning.

Let's say a new aim now is getting known as "www.amazon.de".
Now I try to change the href with javascript:

```
document.getElementById('linkname').setAttribute("href", "www.amazon.de");
```

But my browser creates only a relative link to my domain like this:

```
https://www.mydomain.de/www.amazon.de>
```

*(this is shown if i hover over the link)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because `www.amazon.de` *is* a relative link. To link a different domain (host), you need to begin the [authority component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax) with double slashes: `//www.amazon.de`, or with the scheme included `https://www.amazon.de`.

Comment: OMG! I'm stupid! I did see it but didn't realize it... Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the protocol ('https://') to the link:

```
document.getElementById('linkname').setAttribute("href", "https://www.amazon.de");
```

Comment: Yes. That's just what make it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing 'http://' or 'https://'